# Handle orentation in iOS6 , iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Which all methods are required in iOS 6 to handle orientation? what i have used is given bellow, is this enough?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == interfaceOrientation || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == interfaceOrientation) {
    return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I want to make the application work in both iOS5 and iOS6

Answer (score 0):

before above all steps , set supported orientations in `Targets->Summary`...

[image]

Comment: @trojanfoe: it is just image to show where to set, not actual

Answer (score 0):

I know iOS5 only... one small modification

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

   return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes these three are enough. also for ios6 add the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` with return as

> `return (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft |
>   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)`

method to start the app in your preffered orientation.

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS6**

```
//Support all orientation
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application
    supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**Now you need to change for your root view controller**

```
// iOS6 support
// ---
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

**Deprecated in iOS6, still needed for iOS5 support.**

```
// ---
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is **new** in iOS 6.0, not deprecated!

Comment: Sorry, i put that section in deprecated header. Correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You just add following lines in `.m` file

```
#define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 )
#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )
```

Then you have to add following methods in `.m` file

```
#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
   return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation));
}
#endif

#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
#endif
```